# Laravel 5.1 Redirect after Registration not working

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, registration

I just want to override the `postRegister()` method to avoid Laravel to login the user automatically after registration. So I did inside the **AuthController.php**:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $this->create($request->all());

    return redirect('test');
}
```

Laravel create the user without Login like I want, the problem is in the redirect line. For some very strange reason the always redirect the user to the `'/auth/login'` route.
I commented all my middlewares just to make sure that is not some middleware doing the redirect:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \CapTable\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \CapTable\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'activated' => \CapTable\Http\Middleware\UserActive::class,
];
```

I tried `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan clear:config` to clean all possible cache or config files but Laravel still doing the redirect to `/auth/login`.

After some debug in the code I saw that its reading my new function who overrides the original in vendor.

I really without ideas, someone here had some similar issue or know how can I find out whats is going on here ?

P.S. `test` is just a alias to the route that I want to redirect the user.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the exact route as defined in your route.php

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {

       // your code here

return redirect('/login'); //This is the actual route as defined and not an alias

}
```

If not, try using `return Redirect::to('http://example.com/login');` or `return Redirect::back();`

Comment: No success....its really strange. I had my postLogin function overrided in AuthController and works fine.

Comment: Guys, I solved the problem. My issue was in Angular.js.
In my frontend controller I had one redirection to 'auth/login' that was overriding the backend redirect.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in the backend. I had some redirection in my frontend (Angular.js) that was overriding the Laravel redirection.

```
window.location = '/auth/login';
```

But I learned a important lesson: Always check the frontend.